# How do I get a Date from SQL Server in Crystal Reports 11?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, types

I have a stored procedure that selects from a table, two of the fields are DATE type in SQL Server, but when I select the stored procedure from Crystal Reports, the two date fields appear as Strings (in the YYYY-MM-DD format).  I could write formulas to convert these to the MM/DD/YYYY output that is expected for this report, but is there not a way to get Crystal to recognize SQL Server dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, write formulas, YYYY-MMM-DD is the representation of a date.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: ## Update: ##
While this is true of the DATE datatype, Crystal does correctly recognize the DATETIME type.  Since my procedure's only purpose in life was to provide data to a report, I just modified the procedure's output so that DATETIME fields were used instead of DATE and set the field format to show the date only in crystal.  No formulas required.